# Oracle users with role and previleges

Tags: oracle, user-management

I need a query which contains Oracle users with roles and  privileges  in one query

I Am using Oracle 11G

Comment: There are two data dictionary views: dba_sys_privs and dba_role_privs

Answer (score 0):

Of course roles can be granted to roles, granted to roles .... So if your intent is, as it seems, to see everything a given user has, regardless of directly granted or inherited through a role, through a role, through a role ...  Then the definitive script is found at Pete Finnigan's site.  See http://www.petefinnigan.com/find_all_privs.sql